# Buttons at bottom of the UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to create buttons at bottom of the UITableView. Like in this picture (format buttons):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFgWP.jpg

Should I add the buttons inside a custom UITableViewCell and use this custom cell?
Is it possible to create a UIButton with this style?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the Bold, Italic, etc?

I would recommend you just make a custom cell.

In the cell make a UISegmentedController that has a frame that matches your cell.  I believe that is all they are doing.

Comment: Thank you.. I tried UISegmentedController but I still don't know how can I create a UISegmentedController like in the picture. In the picture the cell that contains segmented control doesn't have a background and segmented control doesn't have left and right corners. Must I to do this with using images?

Comment: Try applying this:  view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES; to your cell.  You will need to make it a unique cell, which I'm assuming you are doing anyway.